# Jquery удаление атрибута у класса при ширине

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня возникает проблема отключения collapse на кнопках.
При разрешении `<=767px` они отключаются удалением атрибута посредством JS, а условие того что при разрешении `>=768px` возвращается атрибут `data-toggle="collapse"` работает только после `785px`, хотя я задал условие оператором `if` (если).
Что может быть не так, объясните пожалуйста новичку:)
Сам сайт trimmeri.by

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= '767'){ // Если меньше 767px то идёт удаление атрибута
       $('.hide-1').removeAttr("data-toggle");
   }
   if ($(window).width() >= '768'){ // Если больше 768px то возврат
       $('.hide-1').attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
   }          
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). Это прям css-синтаксис для проверки текущего размера окна. В вашем случае, не учитывается scroll-бар:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
        $('.hide-1').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    } else {
        $('.hide-1').attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает! И за пояснение большое спасибо:)